# $\oint_C x^4 ds$, where $C: x^2+y^2+z^2=1, x+y+z=0$.

Tags: calculus

> $\oint_C x^4 ds$, where $C: x^2+y^2+z^2=1, x+y+z=0$.

It seems that it is not easy to use the symmetric properties as in calculating $\oint_C x ds, \oint_C x^2 ds$. Any ideas?

$(x+y+z)^4$? $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2$? It seem that does not help.

Comment: I think we should forget about the Stokes Theorem story...

Answer (score 1):

You can parametrize the circle as
$$(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{2+\sin2t}},\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{2+\sin2t}},-\frac{\cos t+\sin t}{\sqrt{2+\sin2t}}\right).$$

Then $ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2+\sin2t}dt$ and hence
$$\int_Cx^4ds=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sqrt3\cos^4t}{(2+\sin2t)^3}dt=\frac\pi 3$$

I partly used WolframAlpha to do computations fastly.

Answer (score 0):

Arc length differential in spherical coordinates $(\rho,\theta,\phi)$, $x=\rho\cos\theta\sin\phi$, $y=\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi$ and $z=\rho\cos\phi,$  is given by
$$ds=\sqrt{(\dot{\rho})^2+\rho^2\sin^2\phi(\dot{\theta})^2+\rho^2(\dot\phi)^2}$$
where the derivative is taken with respect to the paremeter of the curve.
Lets express the curve given by OP in terms of spherical coordinates: $x^2+y^2+z^2=1\implies \rho=1, \dot\rho=0$ and $x+y+z=0\implies\cot\phi=-\cos\theta-\sin\theta$. Let us choose the paremeter as $\theta=t$, $0\leq t\leq 2\pi.$ Then, $\sin\phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2\phi}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+\sin2t}}$ and also $\dot\phi=(\cos t-\sin t)\sin^2\phi$. Hence, the arc length differential is
$$ds=\sqrt{0^2+1^2(\sin^2\phi)1^2+1^2(1-\sin2t)\sin^4\phi}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2+\sin2t}dt.$$
Finally,
$$\int_Cx^4ds=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sqrt3\cos^4t}{(2+\sin2t)^3}dt=\frac\pi3\approx 1.0472.$$